# Interacting with Unix Socket found in lsof

Tags: lsof, unix-sockets

I found a Unix socket being used in the output of the `lsof` command:

```
COMMAND    PID  TID TASKCMD               USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
screen    110970         username    4u     unix 0xffff91fe3134c400       0t0   19075659 socket
```

The "DEVICE" column holds what looks like a memory address.
According to the lsof man page:

```
DEVICE     contains the device numbers, separated by commas, for a character special, block special, regular, directory or NFS file;

                  or ``memory'' for a memory file system node under Tru64 UNIX;

                  or the address of the private data area of a Solaris socket stream;

                  or a kernel reference address that identifies the file (The kernel reference address may be used for FIFO's, for example.);

                  or the base address or device name of a Linux AX.25 socket device.

                  Usually only the lower thirty two bits of Tru64 UNIX kernel addresses are displayed.
```

My question is, which of these am I looking at with the value `0xffff91fe3134c400`?

Also, how can I interact with it? I know I can use `netcat` to connect to a Unix domain socket, but from reading examples online it looks like you have to specify a file.

Comment: Related: [Who's got the other end of this unix socketpair?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/16300)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the file associated with the UNIX socket, you can use the `+E` flag for `lsof` to show the endpoint of the socket. From the man pages:

> +|-E   +E specifies that Linux pipe, Linux UNIX socket and Linux
> pseudoterminal files should be displayed with endpoint
> information and the files of the endpoints should also be
> displayed

For instance, here's some example from a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/687814/273579) someone had where he was trying to find out the endpoint of fd 6 of a `top` process:

```
# lsof -d 6 -U -a +E -p $(pgrep top)
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
dbus-daem   874 messagebus   12u  unix 0xffff9545f6fee400      0t0 366381191 /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket type=STREAM ->INO=366379599 25127,top,6u
top       25127       root    6u  unix 0xffff9545f6fefc00      0t0 366379599 type=STREAM ->INO=366381191 874,dbus-daem,12u
```

The `-U` flag for `lsof` shows only Unix socket files.

Notice that you will only see the name of the socket file for the **listening** processes. The other process will not show the name of the unix socket file, but with `+E` lsof will show the inode of the listening socket file, and will also add a line for the process listening to this socket (along with the socket file name).

In this example notice that we only asked `lsof` to show the file descriptors of `top` command, but `lsof` added another line for `dbus-daem` - which is the listening process, and the socket file it listens to is `/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`.

- Pid 25127 (inode 366379599) interacts with inode 366381191
  (`type=STREAM ->INO=366381191 874,dbus-daem,12u`)
- Inode 366381191 belong to pid 874, and you can see this process has the fd that is the listening side for the second process (`/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket type=STREAM ->INO=366379599 25127,top,6u`), and there you can see that the socket file name is `/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`.

> Also, how can I interact with it?

Now that you have the filename of the UNIX socket, you can interact with it in various ways, such as:

```
socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
nc -U /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
```

For additional information:
[How can I communicate with a Unix domain socket via the shell on Debian Squeeze?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26715/how-can-i-communicate-with-a-unix-domain-socket-via-the-shell-on-debian-squeeze)

Comment: is the `->INO=366381191` an inode? some show the file path but others only show the INO number

Comment: @dcom-launch, I have edited my answer, I hope my clarification helps.

Comment: @aviro "I do not know how to answer your first second question" Is it the "first" or the "second"? XD